# Basement floor drain back up, 1/2" snake failed, what next?

Tags: basement, floor, drain, drainage, drains

The basement floor drain is having backup after the wash cycle from the washer, it doesn't backup from other water usage.

I had a plumber came in to power snake with 1/2" tip (and few other tips) into the floor drain for an hour without success. He suggested the only solution is to break the concrete of the floor and replace the blocked piping.

Is there any less aggressive or cheaper solution I should try first? Someone also suggested me to hire other plumber who has optical device to look at the blockage in the floor drain pipe (for a full diagnostic), do you think it's useful?

Comment: I'd get someone in there with a scope before digging in to the concrete, might end up doing that anyway, but I never trust someone who's first instinct is to crack things open.

Comment: Was the snake not able to get around a bend or something?  A grease and lint ball shouldn't be stronger than a snake.

Comment: How old is this house? Does it have cast iron drain lines?

Comment: I am not sure why the snake doesn't get through, the plumber was doing it with the tenant, is he supposed to be able to diagnose the issue (as to what is causing the stubborn blockage)?

Comment: The house is old (1955 in Canada), I am not sure if it's cast iron, how can I find out and why is it important?

Comment: The reason I asked about cast iron drains is that cast iron drains in contact with soil can fail by corroding. This is happening in my neighborhood of tract houses and "semi-custom" houses on slabs built 1970. As far as I know, the only way to tell what is happening is to have a professional run a camera down the drain. My house is on the last street of 8 built and during the project the builder changed to ABS plastic drains so we haven't had to deal with this, but others have. Some have tunneled under to replace the drains and others have jack hammered holes to replace parts of the drains.

Comment: To tell whether you have plastic (PVC or ABS) or cast iron drains test the end where the washer drains. Is it plastic or heavy metal?

Comment: I think it's metal. Some plumber suggests jetting or flushing, will it risk rupturing the line if it's an old (60 years old) cast iron pipe in the ground?

Comment: Did the plumber say how far the snake went into the line?  That would be a clue as to where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Using a shop vac try sucking on the washer drain line. First fill up the washer drain line with water, then quickly putting the vac hose over the drain.

If you know which is the first sink or toilet below the location of the blockage you could run water into that drain and then put the shop vac on the washer drain. The idea is to relieve the blockage by forcing water in the opposite direction. Sometimes this relieves a blockage when forcing water in the normal drain direction only packs it tighter.

Comment: Can you provide some references of how this is done in details? And can this be done myself given the right tool?

Comment: Do you have a shop vac?

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar problem recently, floor flooding when washer was draining, and what worked made a huge mess but it worked: I filled the vent stack with water (going up on the roof with a hose.  It flooded the sink, but all that weight it pushed through eventually.)

If you try this, try and plug the drains on the first floor, and the laundry sink.  Otherwise as the column of water in the vent builds up it will be flooding out of all your drains.  Once it bursts through you'll heard it whoosh out, and all your drains should be flowing.  This will not work as well if your toilets are on the same vent stack.  In my situation the kitchen (on first) and the laundry (in basement) were sharing a common vent.

Comment: Is this technique called flushing? Any risk of damaging the pipe (and make it worse) if using too much pressure?